# How to convert int64 to Nullable<int64>

Tags: f#

This code:

```
let mutable x : Nullable<int64> = new  Nullable<int64> 99L
let y : int64 = 88L
x <- y
```

produces this compile time error:

> This expression was expected to have type Nullable but here has type int64

I understand the error, what I would like to know is what is the correct way (cast?) to assign the value in `y` (88) to `x`?

Comment: It is far more idiomatic in F# code to use `'t Option` instead of `Nullable` unless you need this for interop with a library.  Also, putting type annotations everywhere is not particularly idiomatic either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [System.Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxxazwb.aspx) constructor; for example:

```
> 
let mutable x = System.Nullable (99L)
let y = 88L
x <- System.Nullable y;;

val mutable x : Nullable<int64> = 88L
val y : int64 = 88L
val it : unit = ()
```